# Flask to Dygraph - how to pass data?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, dygraphs

If I have a simple Python time data series like this:

```
graphdata = []
graphdata.append( [(datetime.date(2008, 5, 7)),75])
graphdata.append([(datetime.date(2008, 5, 8)), 85])
graphdata.append([(datetime.date(2008, 5, 10)), 60])
```

How can I pass the data to a Flask page running Dygraph?

Do I need to use GViz?

Any examples would be helpful.

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass the data as a list containing `datetime` objects. Dygraphs reads CSV format with ease. So just pass the data as one long CSV `string`. For your case, first formulate that string containing your data:

```
graphdata = ''
graphdata = graphdata + '2008-05-07, 75\n'
graphdata = graphdata + '2008-05-08, 85\n'
graphdata = graphdata + '2008-05-10, 60\n'
```

Now, let's say this you wish to render this data on your `index` page, then do this in your `views.py`:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',graphdata)
```

Finally, this data is received by your `index.html` and rendered using the following code:

```
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    {{ graphdata }}

  );
</script>
```

Make sure that `dygraph.js` is included in your Flask app.